# AsdBlog Blog list widget showing image from PageImage Plugin

Tags: impresspages

Is there a simple way to assign image (from PageImage plugin) to the "blog list" widget skin file? Default widget shows image from a block. It would be great, if the "blog list" widget displaying the image from PageImage plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to get images with `\Plugin\PageImage\Service::pageImages($page['id']);` in `Plugin\AsdBlog\Widget\AsdBlogList\skin\default.php` foreach loop. It will contain array with assigned images via PageImage plugin.